# ruby - getting system command stdout with popen3 not working

Tags: ruby, stdout, popen

I am using `lftp` to download some files. Below is the code I'm using and I'd like to capture the stdout. It doesn't show anything though.

If I just run the command in bash I get streaming progress to stdout. I know its stdout because if I `redirect 1 > /dev/null` then the output stops.

Can anyone help please tell me if it's possible to capture stdout of this program?

```
Open3.popen3("lftp -vvv -c 'pget -n 10 ftp://mirror.us.leaseweb.net/debian-cd/7.4.0-live/i386/iso-hybrid/debian-live-7.4-i386-xfce-desktop.iso'") do |stdin, stdout, stderr|
            stdout.sync = true
            stdout.each { |line| puts line }
            stderr.each { |line| puts line }
end
```

UPDATE: looking through the lftp code it uses a '\r' carriage return to have the stdout rewind to start of same line and update rather then take a new line for each. Maybe open3 can't cope well with this.

Comment: What do you want to do with the output?  Store it in a variable?

Comment: The plan is to send a SIGNAL to the script like HUP or something and have it print the status of the current downloading file. So the output would be > /dev/null unless SIGNAL=true, then print one stdout output.